# Text based dungeon game python

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

Can you guys run my code in Jupyter note and please tell me whats wrong with it? I don't seem to understand why it doesn't work like it should. Everytime I choose and item from inventory, it gives me game over. I want the code to print whenever the dragon defeated or not and the print statement to next room.

```
import sys

print("""Hello! Type 1 to Continue""")

#ice sword - a

#fire sword - b

#electric sword - c

inv = {'a':'Ice Sword'}

#function to display the inventory

def display():
    print("type 1 to display your inventory\n")

n = input()

if int(n)==1:

    for i in inv:

        print(i +" - "+ inv[i])

    sequence = ['c','a','b']

for i in range(0,4):

#room-1 Fire dragon - ice sword win-firesword

    if i==0:

        print("You are in room-1 a FIRE DRAGON appears\n")

display()

print("choose your Item")

x = input()

if x == 'a' and i==0:

    print("The fire dragon is defeated proceed to next room\n")
    print("You have acquired a new Item 'Fire Sword'\n")

    inv['b'] = 'Fire Sword'

else:
    print("---GAME OVER---")




#room-2 Electric dragon - ice sword win-electric sword

if i==1:

    print("You are in room-2 a ELECTRIC DRAGON appears\n")

display()

print("choose your Item")

x = input()

if x=='a' and i==1:

    print("The electric dragon is defeated you proceed next room\n")

    print("You have acquired a new Item 'Electric Sword'\n")

    inv['c'] = 'Electric Sword'

else:

    print("---GAME OVER---")



#room-3 Ice dragon - fire sword win-key

if i==2:

    print("You are in room-3 a Ice dragon appears\n")

    display()

print("choose your Item")

x = input()

if x=='b' and i==2:

    print("The Ice dragon is defeated you __ next room\n")

    print("You have acquired a new Item 'Key'\n")

    inv['d'] = 'Key'

else:

    print("---GAME OVER---")



#room-4 Dark beast Ganon specific order ([c a b])

if i==3:

    print("Use the key you won to enter the last room\n")

display()

print("choose your Item")

x = input()

if x=='d' and i==3:

    print("The Final boss DARK BEAST GANON appears\n")

else:

    print("---GAME OVER---")



#used the key and the boss appears

print("to defeat this boss you need to use a specific combination of the swords\n")

print("Enter the sequence one by one and press enter after every value")

a = []

for i in range(0,3):

    x = input()

a.append(x)

if a == sequence:

    print("Congratulation you have completed the game")



#sys.exit()



else:

    print("---GAME OVER---")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a badly constructed question. Not only do we need more context to everything that's happening, but I would also recommend you point to specifically the lines of code where the problem occurs from, and in this case where the code for where the 'game ends' as well.

Furthermore, it won't matter if it's run in Jupyter or not, it will work in the same way where ever it's run as long as the version of Python you're using is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your bug comes as a side effect of this loop:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    if i==0:  #room-1 Fire dragon - ice sword win-firesword
        print("You are in room-1 a FIRE DRAGON appears\n")

display()

print("choose your Item")
x = input()
if x == 'a' and i==0:
```

Note that even though you're only printing if `i==0`, the loop still executes through `i=1`, `i=2`, and `i=3`. The last line I highlighted, `if x == 'a' and i==0:`, evaluates to False because `i==0` is False at this point - `i` is `3` (since the loop has finished).